# Getting invalid date from moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I have a redis stored timestamp when I get it, it looks like this:

`1454803149444`

Then when I try to do:

```
i.text-muted.createdAtPost= moment(post.timestamp).format("MM/DD/YY @ h:mm:ss") // Jade Template
```

I get

`Invalid Date`

But if I take the same integer, and go `moment(1454803149444).format(h:mm:ss")` I get `05/21/54 @ 12:00:00`

Any information would be great thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. What I did was

```
let time = post.timestamp / 1000;
let formatted = moment.unix(time).format("MM/DD/YY @ h:mm:ss");
```

I have no idea why this works. I tried forcing the value into an integer and still got invalid date. I hard coded the value that was console logged and it worked, like in your case. For some reason dividing it by 1000 and calling it a unix timestamp works fine. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I think this answer may clarify why the need to divide it by 1000. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925853/6654475. In summary a conversion between seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

What value does `timestamp` pass?
Did you check that?
If it has a specific format you need to set it as:

```
moment(post.timestamp, 'YYYY/DD/MM').format("MM/DD/YY @ h:mm:ss")
```