# Moment.js , Invalid date time when converting epochtime

Tags: javascript, momentjs, epoch

I have following code to convert epochtime to dateTime.

```
var newDate = moment.unix(1525168800000).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
alert(newDate);
```

When I check the time stamp at [epochtimeconvetrer](https://www.epochconverter.com/), I get back the correct time,

```
GMT: Tuesday, May 1, 2018 10:00:00 AM
```

But when I try to get the same value by parsing with moment, getting invalid date ,

```
09/05/50300
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLc4wops/1/

Comment: Some one care why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is *seconds from epoch*. What you're passing is *milliseconds from epoch*. Divide the value by 1000, before passing it to the method:

```
moment.unix(1525168800).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
// "05/01/2018"
```

Alternatively, you can pass the value directly to `moment()` constructor, which accepts *milliseconds from epoch*.

```
moment(1525168800000).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
// "05/01/2018"
```

When you paste the value to the epochconverter, and try to convert it, the site clearly shows a message which says "Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds". See the snapshot below:

[image]

And that's why, it shows the result correctly.

Comment: Thanks , it helps, and for sure will help many. Marking as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply instantiate with the number of milliseconds from the Unix epoch, just like a Date.

```
var newDate = moment(1525168800000).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
alert(newDate);
```